# How to secure REST API using external authorization server using minimal configuration in C# .NET

Tags: java, c#, .net, jwt

I have been working in Java for couple of years and recently switched to C# .NET. One of the common scenarios I was dealing with as backend developer was building secured REST API. Each request to the API contains Authorization header with Bearer access token. We use AWS Cognito as an external authorization server.

In Spring Boot, this was fairly easy task:

1. use spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

2. add security configuration

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   http.cors()
       .and()
       .csrf(CsrfConfigurer::disable)
       .sessionManagement(SessionManagementConfigurer::disable)
       .authorizeRequests(c -> c.anyRequest().authenticated())
       .oauth2ResourceServer()
       .jwt();
   return http.build();
}
```

3. define issuer-uri and jwk-set-uri properties

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri: ...
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri: ...
```

Now with this fairly generic configuration, all endpoints are secured.

However, I am unable to find the way to implement the same thing in C# .NET. All the tutorials and articles I found followed different approach, all of them bounding the solution with user management. What I am looking for is a pure resource server. Any help or pointing in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: What does "bounding the solution with user management" mean?

Comment: Try to share some of the approaches you already have tried and your problems with them, so people can see what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I managed to come up with the solution, leaving it here as it may save someone else's time as well. Picked up Asgardeo this time as the external authorization server. Solution was tested in .NET 6.0:

1. add authentication

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Audience = "<client_id>";
    options.MetadataAddress = "https://api.asgardeo.io/t/<app_name>/oauth2/token/.well-known/openid-configuration";
});
```

2. use authentication (authentication, authorization and controller mapping must be in correct order)

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
```

3. add secured endpoint to controller

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Private")]
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Private()
{
    return Ok(new
    {
        Message = "Hello from a private endpoint."
    });
}
```

This solution works for applications without client secret.